# Is there a Frame node in Sverchok addon?

Tags: node-editor, sverchok

In the material and compositing node editor, frames are use to organize the node tree:
[image]

Sverchok doesn't seem to have frames:

[image]

Is it possible to add frames to Sverchok node trees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ctrl+j will add selected nodes to frame